# Pass password from jenkins to shell script which is located in another linux server not in jenkins server

Tags: shell, jenkins

I am using SSHPASS command to copy files from Linux to Windows server in shell script. The problem is password is exposed and anyone can use this credentials and delete some files.

So avoid this problem can we pass password from Jenkins to shell script which is located in Linux server. If so please let me know how it can be configured.

Answer (score 0):

If your only problem is to avoid exposing the password on the console output, you can write the password inside a file and send it through scp to the destination server

after that, you are able to get the password with the cat command like

```
ENV_PASSWORD=$(cat /path/your_password_file)
```

Your password will the ready to use from the env var

Answer (score 0):

If you can have your Windows configured to allow login via key instead of password, you can use the [SSH Agent plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/ssh-agent/).

1. Install the plugin via jenkins plugin management interface
2. Create a new crendential in your Jenkins of type "SSH Username with private key"
3. Change your project build configuration to start the SSH agent providing the credential you just created
4. Modify your script to perform a copy without proving any password